# Implementing an RSS feed using refinery CMS / RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, refinerycms

I am fairly new to both RoR and refinery CMS (although, very seasoned C#/ASP.net developer) - I followed the tutorial on their website;

http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started-with-refinery

and have taken it to the point where I'm pretty sure this is the CMS I'm going to use... but I'm struggling a bit with the implementation of an RSS feed (basically because it's taken over the controller).

I'm not looking for the whole answer/code (I kinda like figuring out the details myself) but could someone give me a nudge in the right direction? How, for example, would I make Rick Astley's "events" in the tutorial appear on an RSS feed?

I was trying to achieve this by overriding the events controller, to get something like this occuring;

http://localhost:3000/events/rss

but it keeps thinking that I'm trying to find an event with the ID of "rss" and falling over. I know I'm barking up completely the wrong tree here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing's first, you will want to update your routes.rb to

get 'events/rss' => 'events#index', :format => :rss

But, also, the refinerycms-calendar has RSS:
https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-calendar

http://localhost:3000/events.rss should work by default for this engine

Comment: cheers bud - decided to go back to the drawing board and learn basic rails before asking any more questions like this as it's clear I'm missing the basics!

Comment: Yes... refinery can be daunting if you are new to Rails, because you don't know what's refinery magic vs. rails magic ... and come to think of it, what's vs. ruby power! Best of luck! irc.freenode.net #refinerycms is available as well